# Qt can't find openssl

Tags: qt, openssl, libraries, qsslsocket

I installed Qt 4.8 from developer.nokia website which is a `.run` file. Because it's from nokia i assume the libraries are compiled with openssl...
I use ubuntu 11.10 and it has openssl already installed.
I can't make the QSsl classes working because of this, what am i doing wrong?

Anyone know a proper Qt SDK 4.8 that works fine?

Thanks!

Comment: can you compile the code correctly in your_qt_directory/example/network/securesocketclient?

Comment: it's not about compiling. everything compiles fine. the problem is `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 export QTDIR=/home/user/qtsdk-2010.05/
 export PATH=$QTDIR/bin:$QTDIR/qt/bin:$PATH
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/qtsdk-2010.05/lib/:/home/user/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

please change qtsdk-2010.05 to your sdk path

and make sure the binary path and lib is correct, then `qmake ,make clean , make`

Comment: but i don't use qt commercial. I installed the free qt version

Comment: free version is ok , just change the binary path and lib path to your own sdk, then qmake ,make clean , make

Comment: I have replace the commercial with another version

Comment: still doesn't work... `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` still returns false... :(

Comment: what is the output of:  ldd  your_binary_file |grep qt -i ?

Comment: i get nothing: `a@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ldd QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run | grep qt -i `
`a@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ `

Comment: your_binary_file should be the executable file of your own application ,not QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run. For example ldd myapp |grep qt -i

Comment: first line:
`libQtGui.so.4 => /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007fdea84be000)`
second line:
`libQtNetwork.so.4 => /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007fdea8163000)`
third line:
`libQtCore.so.4 => /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007fdea7c6f000)`

Comment: how about  ldd your_binary_file |grep ssl -i ?

Comment: maybe you can goto http://qt.digia.com/ to  get qt5.0.0 and give a try ,you can get a 30 day license .

Comment: i'm willing to create a ssl connection between a client and a server using qsslsocket and i think qt 5 has some bugs because it makes the connection crash. I tested on a qt 4.8 on a friend computer on mac and linux and works fine. qt5 crashes.
I'm talking about this example: `https://github.com/dgraves/QSslChat`

Comment: another solution is to edit you pro file , add "LIBS += -Wl,-rpath, /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/", then make clean ,qmake,make; let's see whether it can work or not

Comment: i get `:-1: error: cannot find /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/: File format not recognized` :(

Comment: /home/a/.QtSDK/ is your install path right? is there any file inside /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/?

Comment: it should be QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -Wl,-rpath, /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib

Comment: File format not recognized? how about the output of "file /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4"

Comment: error is: `:-1: error: cannot find /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib: File format not recognized` output of the command you suggested is `/home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4: symbolic link to `libQtNetwork.so.4.8.1'
`

Comment: please check the result of "file /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.1"

Comment: `/home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
`

Comment: please change "QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath, /home/a...." to  QMAKE_RPATHDIR += /home/a/.QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib and give a try

Comment: this time code compiles but `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` still returns false :(

Comment: does this command works in your computer "openssl s_client -connect www.paypal.com:443"

Comment: no, it has `QT += core gui network` but i tried also to add widgets and it still does not recognize ssl

Comment: qt += core gui network is ok, "I tested on a qt 4.8 on a friend computer on mac and linux and works fine" do you mean the same sdk (qt4.8.1)works fine on other linux machine ?

Comment: you can use "strace ./your_app_name >& 1.log" to check whether ssl lib is missing , I guess your /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 is missing

Comment: if so,please reinstall it using "sudo apt-get --reinstall install libssl1.0.0"

Comment: thank you very much for your help. libssl1.0.0 was already installed. I solved the problem installing `qt-sdk` from the repos. I have no idea why the sdk from nokia's website is not working well.
I also tried sudo `apt-get --reinstall install libssl1.0.0`.
If you have other ideas please share, maybe someone encounters the same problem and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem installing `qt-sdk` from the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

A newer version of the Qt Creator can be found on `qt-project.org`

However for `Ubuntu 11.10` `Qt 4.7` will be installed and not `4.7`. `Qt 4.8` is available on the newer `Ubuntu` versions' repositories.